# Fonts has wrong path in Vite build file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I have a `stylesheet` in `css` folder and a few fonts in `fonts` folder. `fonts` and `css` folders are in the same directory.

#### folder structure

```
|-fonts
|   |--- a.woff
|   |--  b.woff2      
|
|-css
    |--- typography.css
```

I have used `a.woff` and `b.woff2` in `typography.css` like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "basis-pro";
  src: url("../fonts/a.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("../fonts/b.woff") format("woff");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

I have changed `base`,  `rollupOptions.outPut` and `outDir` of `vite.config.js`.

```
export default defineConfig({
  base: "./",
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
          var info = assetInfo.name.split(".");
          var extType = info[info.length - 1];
          if (/png|jpe?g|svg|gif|tiff|bmp|ico/i.test(extType)) {
            extType = "img";
          } else if (/woff|woff2/.test(extType)) {
            extType = "fonts";
          }
          return `static/${extType}/[name]-[hash][extname]`;
        },
        chunkFileNames: "static/js/[name]-[hash].js",
        entryFileNames: "static/js/[name]-[hash].js",
      },
    },
    outDir: "./../backend/src/main/resources/static/app/",
  },
});
```

All of the assets have correct path excepts fonts when building the app.

`fonts` are generated in `fonts` and `css` files are genereted in `css` folder. But the two fonts in a css file has wrong path.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "basis-pro";
  src: url("./a.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("./b.woff") format("woff");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

It must be like the following as my assets has the same folder structure as the above (folder structure).

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "basis-pro";
  src: url("../fonts/a.woff2") format("woff2"),
    url("../fonts/b.woff") format("woff");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-display: swap;
}
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: it's something related to your folder structure and the value set to **base** `./`. If you set an alias pointing to your fonts folder and adjust the paths on the css calls, it will work. Anyway as tony suggest, you should share something reproducible.